# Set foreign key values based on existing column data

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, database-normalization

I am in the middle of migrating an old (unnormalized) database to its new version.

Right now I have this intermediate result:

```
    CREATE TABLE recipient(
        id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        email VARCHAR(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE INDEX (`email`),
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;

    CREATE TABLE comment(
        # Right now this is always NULL:
        fk_recipient INT,
        # Temporary solution. Note that this field is NOT UNIQUE:
        tmp_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        # ...
        FOREIGN KEY (`fk_recipient`) REFERENCES recipient(id);
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Both tables are filled with correct data:

- some million comments with the right `tmp_email` and `fk_recipient = null` in table `comment` (note: emails are not unique)
- some hundred thousand UNIQUE email adresses in table `recipient`.

**What I need to do:**

I want to get rid of the `comment.tmp_email` column and instead point `comment.fk_recipient` to the appropriate row in table `recipient`.

**My current approach (using PHP):**

1. get all comments
2. iterate over all comments:

   - look up the right row in `recipient` table
   - set right foreign key
3. `... DROP COLUMN tmp_email`

This takes forever and made me wonder if there is no native MySQL way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following workaround will do the job:

1. Create temporary foreign key on `comment.tmp_email`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE comment
       ADD CONSTRAINT `tmpMailKey` FOREIGN KEY (`tmp_email`)
       REFERENCES `recipient`(`email`);
   ```
2. Join the two tables on the temporary key and use the information to set the real foreign key:

   ```
   UPDATE comment c
   INNER JOIN recipient r
   ON
           c.tmp_email = r.email
       AND c.tmp_email IS NOT NULL
   SET c.fk_recipient = r.id;
   ```
3. Get rid of temporary foreign key (and the tmp column too):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `udw_v3`.`travelogue_guestbookentry`
       DROP COLUMN `tmp_email`,
       DROP INDEX `tmpMailKey`,
       DROP FOREIGN KEY `tmpMailKey`;
   ```